# Colouring specific label in ggplot depending on the value of the id variable on a long data (irrespectively of the row number)

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2, label, subset

Let's say that I have a long data set and I would like to colour a specific label on the x-axis. In the case of the example below I would like to colour the label for *Valiant*.

```
# Packs
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)

# Data and trans
data(mtcars)
mtcars$model <- rownames(mtcars)
mtcars <- melt(mtcars, id.vars = "model")

# Some chart
ggplot(data = subset(x = mtcars, subset = mtcars$variable == "cyl"), 
       aes(x = model, y = value)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, 
                                     colour =
                                         ifelse(mtcars$model == "Valiant",
                                                "red","black")))
```

The code produces the chart below that is erroneous as the wrong label is coloured.

[image: Wrong label]

The reason is fairly simple as what is created by `ifelse` does not match the order on the axis. I can fix the code by forcing `ggplot` to colour a specific row. The code below colours the right label as in the particular `data.frame` used for the chart the row with the *Valiant* value is **31**.

```
# Fixed chart
ggplot(data = subset(x = mtcars, subset = mtcars$variable == "cyl"), 
       aes(x = model, y = value)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, 
                                     colour =
                                         ifelse(as.numeric(rownames(mtcars)) == 31,
                                                "red","black")))
```

[image: Fixed label]

Clearly this solutions is extremely impractical. On the actual data I've a vast number of observations with multiple columns (geo, gender, indicator, value, etc.). That data is subsequently filtered via subset and different options are passed to the `aes` settings. Trying to figure out the row that should be coloured is a nightmare. I'm looking for a solution that would enable me to:

- Relatively effortless indicate specific observation to be coloured without trying to use row numbers
- Ideally I would like to use the `id` with some string as a way of indicating the text I wan to highlight
- I would like to encapsulate the solution in the `ggplot2` code, I don't want to create separate data subsets only to derive colouring vector as I will be doing this a number of times. This would unnecessary multiply objects.
- In practice, I want solution that would work like that: *irrespectively of what is on the chart, when you find this string on x-axis make it red*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the first one mismatches is that `mtcars$model` is much longer than the subset you are plotting, so the colour vector `ifelse(mtcars$model == "Valiant","red","black")` is of length 352 but the subset you are plotting is only of length 32. The same problem exists with your second example, though in this case the extra elements of `colour` (which are all "black" anyway) are dropped so you don't notice.

Unfortunately it looks like `theme(...)` doesn't get evaluated with the data column-names available to it (i.e. can't just do `colour=ifelse(model == "Valiant", "red", "black")` directly in the `theme(...)` call)

One alternative is to make `model` a factor and filter on `levels(..) == "Valiant"`. If you have a long dataframe your id variable is most likely a factor anyway (or it would make sense for it to be one).

```
mtcars$model = factor(mtcars$model)
ggplot(data=subset(mtcars, variable == 'cyl'), aes(x=model, y=value)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,
              colour=ifelse(levels(mtcars$model) == 'Valiant', 'red', 'black')))
```

(your problem stems from feeding `subset()` into ggplot as your data, and then not being able to refer back to that particular subset in the `theme` call. I don't know if there is a tricksy way to do this).

Comment: Thanks, it's a good solution. In terms of usability, it would be easier to encapsulate the first line and and the `ifelse` statement in a function. I experimented with levels but it didn't occur to me to apply `factor` on the actual column first.