# Label or Highlight Specific Rows in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-tile

I have a great looking geom_tile plot, but I need a way to highlight specific rows or label specific rows based on a binary value.

Here is a small subset of data in wide format and resulting output:

```
df <- structure(list(bin_level = c(0,1), sequence = c("L19088.1", "chr1_43580199_43586187"), X236 = c("G", "."), X237 = c("G", "."), X238 = c("A", "a"), 
    X239 = c("T", "C"), X240 = c("A", "c"), X241 = c("G", "G"
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2)


> df
  bin_level               sequence X236 X237 X238 X239 X240 X241
1         0               L19088.1    G    G    A    T    A    G
2         1 chr1_43580199_43586187    .    .    a    C    c    G
```

The actual dataset is much larger, with 1045 observations of 3096 variables.

My goal is to plot this massive dataset as a heatmap with colors for each different nucleotide *and* be able to differentiate between rows with bin_levels of 0 and 1.

The following code makes a great plot, but doesn't include the bin_level differences I need to see. I would like to highlight the entire row if the bin_level is 1, but I haven't been able to find anything on how to do such a thing. I am already using nucleotides for the aes fill variable, so I need something else. The best option I've come up with so far is to color the row labels. I used info from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418568/colouring-specific-label-in-ggplot-depending-on-the-value-of-the-id-variable-on) to try an ifelse statement to color based on the bin_level variable.

The biggest problems here are

1. Row axis titles are much too long and too many to look good
2. There are only 53 bin_level rows with a 1 (of 1045 total), so why does it look like a LOT more red than there should be?
3. I want the red labels (bin_level =1's) at the top of the plot, and the mix of black/red makes me think my arrange(bin_level) piece isn't working right.

Please let me know if you know of a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish, or can help make my code work better than it is currently. Thank you!

```
df %>%
  ## reshape to long table
  ## (one column each for sequence, position and nucleotide):
  pivot_longer(-c("Sequence", "bin_level"), ## stack all columns *except* sequence and bin_level
               names_to = 'position',
               values_to = 'nucleotide'
  ) %>%
  arrange(bin_level) %>%
  ## create the plot:
  ggplot() +
  geom_tile(aes(x = position, y = Sequence, fill = nucleotide),
            height = 1 ## adjust to visually separate sequences
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('a'='#ea0064', 'c'='#008a3f', 'g'='#116eff',
                               't'='#cf00dc', '\U00B7'='#000000', 'X' ='#ffffff'
  )
  ) +
  labs(x = 'x-axis-title', y='Sequence') +
  ## remove x-axis (=position) elements: they'll probably be too dense:
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = ifelse(levels(df$bin_level)==1, "red", "black"))
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity: you initially wanted to save your plot as a PDF. How long does this PDF take to open with > 3m elements to be rendered?

Comment: @I_O Surprisingly it's quite fast!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While passing a vector of colors to `element_text()` is a quick option in some cases IMHO in more general cases it is error prone and requires to keep an eye on the way you ordered your data. Instead I would suggest to have a look at the `ggtext` package which introduces the theme element `element_markdown` and allows for styling text using some HTML, CSS and markdown.

Moreover, besides the issue already pointed out by @I_O another issue is that you wrangle the data manipulation steps together with the plotting code in one pipeline. As a consequence while you arrange your data by `bin_level` you use the original unmanipulated, unarranged dataset `df` which by the way is still in wide format for the color assignment. That's why personally I would always recommend to split the data wrangling and the plotting except for very simple cases.

Finally, while your arranged your data by `bin_level` what really matters is the order of `sequence`, i.e. you have to set the order of `sequence` after arranging for which I use `forecast::fct_inorder`.

Note: To make your example more realistic I duplicated your dataset to add two more rows.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df_long <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c("sequence", "bin_level"),
    names_to = "position",
    values_to = "nucleotide"
  ) %>%
  arrange(bin_level) %>%
  mutate(
    sequence = if_else(bin_level == 1, paste0("<span style='color: red'>", sequence, "</span>"), sequence),
    sequence = forcats::fct_inorder(sequence))

ggplot(df_long) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = position, y = sequence, fill = nucleotide),
    height = 1
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(
    "a" = "#ea0064", "c" = "#008a3f", "g" = "#116eff",
    "t" = "#cf00dc", "\U00B7" = "#000000", "X" = "#ffffff"
  )) +
  labs(x = "x-axis-title", y = "Sequence") +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = ggtext::element_markdown()
  )
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(
  bin_level = c(0, 1), sequence = c("L19088.1", "chr1_43580199_43586187"), X236 = c("G", "."), X237 = c("G", "."), X238 = c("A", "a"),
  X239 = c("T", "C"), X240 = c("A", "c"), X241 = c("G", "G")
), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2)

df1 <- structure(list(
  bin_level = c(0, 1), sequence = c("L19088.2", "chr1_43580199_43586187.2"), X236 = c("G", "."), X237 = c("G", "."), X238 = c("A", "a"),
  X239 = c("T", "C"), X240 = c("A", "c"), X241 = c("G", "G")
), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2)

df <- dplyr::bind_rows(df, df1)
```

Comment: This is so great! It works great, except that now I am struggling to shorten the y axis labels since they're so cumbersome. Any good ideas for that?

Comment: Hm. A general approach would be use e.g. `str_wrap` to wrap the labels (if you want to try that: Keep in mind that you first have to wrap, then set the colors, then order) which however will put the labels on multiple lines. And I'm afraid that this will not work great with your real data. When I run in such issues I normally try to replace long labels with shorter ones. But whether this could be done and whether this is appropriate depends on the data or the topic. And I'm afraid as an economist I lack your domain knowledge to guide you on that.

Answer (score 0):

While you arrange the data by bin level before feeding it into ggplot, the plot's vertical arrangement follows the y-value (which is: sequence). You could create a combination of bin_level and sequence to arrange and plot the data by:

```
df %>%
    ...
    ## reformat bin_level to a three-digit character, so that
    ## 002 properly precedes 011 (otherwise 11 would come before 2) 
    mutate(dummy = paste(sprintf('%03.0f', bin_level),
                   Sequence, sep = '_')) %>%
    arrange(dummy) %>%
    ...

## ggplot instructions:
ggplot() + ... +
    geom_tile(aes(y = dummy, ...)) +
    ## remove the bin_level prefix ('00x_') for labelling:
    scale_y_discrete(labels = gsub('.*_', '', df$dummy)) +
    ... +
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(
                        ## note: df$bin_level NOT levels(df$bin_level)
                        colour = ifelse(df$bin_level == 1, "red", "black"))
    )
```

mind that using element_text to colour labels might not function in the future:

> Vectorized input to `element_text()` is not officially supported.
> Results may be unexpected or may change in future versions of ggplot2.
> (console warning)